# Why does upgrading Chrome and Chrome driver stop web application from loading

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, centos7, webdriver-io

I'm Running E2E testing on a web application in Jenkins using a centos node with Webdriver IO.

Chrome: google-chrome-stable-96.0.4664.110-1.x86_64.rpm

Chrome driver:

```
sh 'sudo yum info google-chrome-stable | grep Version > chromeOutFile'
                    def CHROME_VERSION = readFile('chromeOutFile')
                    def Version = CHROME_VERSION.split('Version     :')
                    def VersionNumber = Version[1].trim()
                    sh "./src/main/web/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=${VersionNumber}"
```

I'd like to update this to user the latest version of Chrome with a corresponding Chrome Driver.

Webdriver IO config:

```
services: [['chromedriver', {
        chromedriverCustomPath: '../node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_96.0.4664.110'
    }]],
```

Problem: when I try to use a more up-to-date version, even if it's chromedriver_97.0.4692.99, my web application no longer starts up in Jenkins. When I try to visit the url, the screen shot just shows a blank screen. I'm not sure the application is even loading.

Why does it only work with 96 but not others?

I tried to map the version of Chrome with an appropriate version of chrome driver using https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_97.0.4692 but that still doesn't work for me.

Running tests:

```
cd e2e && wdio run wdio.ci.conf.ts --suite access --logLevel=info

+ lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

Comment: Did you tried opening your web directly on that chrome in your centos node?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check memory limits? I had a similar problem with automated testing and had to change memory limits to either 1) limit chrome's memory or 2) pre allocate a set amount of memory ahead of time from my webserver if you are testing on the same device.